# $_FILE single quotes causes empty name

Tags: php

If i upload file with single quotes that will cause empty name when i do print_r to $_FILE. for example, file named `2'.ogg` that system would output `.ogg`. I think that windows causes this, but i'm not sure. here the code i'm using:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
   print_r($_FILES); 
}
echo <<<Print
<form action='' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="t[]"> <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
Print;
?>
```

Comment: Need to check raw http request with this filename. addslashes is not needed. Maybe it's the "magic quotes" issue in old PHP.

Comment: I thought about it, but there is no magic quotes in new versions.

Comment: browser sends filename like this `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="t[]"; filename="2'.ogg"`. Maybe server incorrectly parses this single quote.

Comment: So what can i do to solve this?

Comment: tried this case on apache/php5.6, and found no problem with single quotes. Have to find software or module that parses the filename.

Comment: Anyone has any clue what could corrupt that?

Answer (score 0):

Use addslashes() to escape single quote and stripcslashes() to remove added slashes.